# In CSS, three containers in a row: how do you put the ends at the extremes and the middle container in the center of the row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

If you don't need to use flexbox then that's fine, since that paradigm may not be possible at accomplishing this. Here is the html:

```
    <div className="App">
      <div className="first">First</div>
      <div className="second">Second</div>
      <div className="third">Third</div>
    </div>
```

And here is the basic CSS:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  width: 30px;
}

.second {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.third {
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried setting the left and right divs to have `auto` margins but no luck. How to center the second div?

Edit: not sure why they deleted my screenshot so let me add it back
[image: non-centered middle container!]